# Does Liquibase needs write permission to acquire lock?

Tags: java, database, liquibase

Considering this

```
INFO 8/4/12 7:16 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 8/4/12 7:16 AM:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: `DATABASECHANGELOG`
INFO 8/4/12 7:16 AM:liquibase: Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
INFO 8/4/12 7:16 AM:liquibase: Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
INFO 8/4/12 7:16 AM:liquibase: ChangeSet db.changelog.xml::1::shameer ran successfully in 74ms
INFO 8/4/12 7:16 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Liquibase Update Successful
```

I am not sure if liquibase needs to write to database in order to

```
Successfully acquired change log lock
```

The reason is that temporarily I do not have `read-write` password, but just `read-only` password with me, to deploy to production

I wanted to check if liquibase will be able to lock the database.

P.S. Since the database state has not changed, it is not needed to apply any new changesets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Liquibase inserts a row into the table DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK to lock the schema.
It deletes the row to unlock the schema.

Comment: Yes, liquibase updates a row in the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table so there is no attempts at concurrent updates. If you want to avoid it, you can use the https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-nochangeloglock extension.

You will need read-write logic to apply changeSets, obviously. If you are wanting to check the state of a changelog vs the database you may want to use the "liquibase status" command